# analytic in open disc and $|f| = 1$ on boundary

Tags: complex-analysis

$f$ is a function such that it is analytic in an open disc and on the boundary of the disc absolute value of $f$ is $1$. 
Does such function exist?

Comment: $f(z) = z$ on the unit disk is the most trivial non-constant example. There are many more.

Answer (score 2):

Any Daniel Fischer notes, any $f(z)=z^n$ will work. But there are many more.

In the context of Hardy space theory, such functions are called inner functions. See [here](http://www1.maths.leeds.ac.uk/~pmt6jrp/yorkleeds.pdf) for more information. In particular, corollary 2.2 gives a characterization of inner functions.

Answer (score 1):

There are many such functions. There is also a theorem which states that : 
Suppose $f:\mathbb{D} \to \mathbb{D}$ is holomorphic with $a_1,a_2,...,a_n$ its zeros inside the disc, with $|f(z)|=1$ for every $z \in \partial \mathbb{D}$. Then $f$ is a Blaschke Product $$ f(z)=e^{i\theta}\prod_{k=1}^{n} \frac{z-a_k}{1-\bar{a_k}z}$$